# dynamic meta data and description for pages

Tags: php

I am developing pages in php dynamically i.e data gets filled up from mysql DB. how do i assign a proper meta data and description for these dynamic pages so that google recognises it properly.

What needs to be passed in page so that google takes description properly. when i search a page in google. it takes the data in page as description not description tag contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $your_meta_description ?>" />`

Comment: but when i am building a page .i build only body part and the head section is included which is a single file.

Comment: then you need to look at your ordering, assign the meta data BEFORE your header is included.

Comment: i will explain my structure . say i have a page called index.php  .. it will look like
 <?php  include('header.php);
  echo 'this is body part';
include('footer.php); ?>

so header contains all header part. so from body section can i set the meta description?

Comment: no, but you can do:
<?php $meta = 'description'; include('header.php); echo 'this is body part'; include('footer.php); ?>

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are using to build your site. Wordpress, for instance, doesn't come with meta description functionality by default. You would need to use a plugin.

Google will use your description only if it contains the keyword been searched for, and if it confirms that the meta description supplied accurately describes the content of the page.

This article might help: [How to specify how your site looks in the search engines](http://intellichristian.net/how-to-specify-how-your-site-looks-in-the-search-engines)