# how to change metadata on preview link dynamically?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, metadata

I am working on a project where one page display products dynamically depending on URL parameters `website/product.html?p=productNumberHere`. Now when I share a page of any product the preview link values (title and description) doesn't change even though it **changed ** when I load the page. So, is it possible to change metadata values in preview link?

I made a function at the top of the page to change the meta description. it changed on loading the page, but didn't in preview link.

```
<head id="hd">
    <title id="productNameq"></title>
    <script>
        function metaFunction() {
            var m = document.createElement("meta");
                        m.name = "description";
                        m.content = "product description";

            document.getElementById("hd").appendChild(m);

        }
        metaFunction();
        
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that metadata information should be generated from the back-end for this case.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim html As String = "<html><head>"
  html += "<meta name = 'title' content='" & title & "' /> "
  html += " <meta name = 'description' content='" & description & "' />"
  html += "<meta property='og:title' content='" & title & "'>"
  html += "<meta property='og:description' content='" & description & "'>"
  html += "<meta property='og:image' content='" & img & "'>  
  html += "<meta property='og:Image:width' content='200' />"
  html += "<meta Property='og:Image:height' content='200' />"
  html += "</head><body>"
  html += "</body></html>"

  Response.Write(html)
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your script runs at client side (in browser). On the other hand link preview generation stage uses requested HTML code as is, i.e. **without executing client-side scripts**. Read more about the process [here](https://technoteshelp.com/how-do-i-preview-a-url/).

If you are going to use different `<meta />` depending on a parameter, then do it by means of server-side scripting, [such as PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942352/dynamic-meta-data-and-description-for-pages).